# Firebug style inspector using Chrome Inspector

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools

When using Firebug extension, I'm able to click the pointer icon and as I move my mouse over the web page, it will highlight the div I'm on both visually over the element, and also in the code source in the panel beneath.

I cannot figure out, if I'm using a native inspector (like the one for chrome) how to accomplish the same result?  As I move my mouse over images on the web page in chrome, nothing happens, but if I move my mouse over the source code panel of the inspector, elements in the page will highlight.

It seems far more easier to me to point to some visual element on the page vs moving your mouse up and down code to find the element to select.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Firebug and the native Firefox DevTools implement this.

Web Inspector/Chrome DevTools do not have that feature. You may want to file an enhancement request for them, though:

- Web Inspector: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector
- Chrome DevTools: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=Cr%3DPlatform-DevTools

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when it was added, or if it was missed but chrome now accomplishes what I am looking for.

[image: magnifying glass top left]

Click the magnifying glass on the top left.  This will allow pointing to elements on the web page.